# Identification of terms

Tags: series-expansion, sorting

I have the following sum on terms:

```
-((920 g20 g2L P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^7)) - (20 g20 g2L L1^4 P2)/(
 L2^4 (L1 + L2)^5 r^7) - (136 g20 g2L L1^3 P2)/(
 L2^3 (L1 + L2)^5 r^7) - (416 g20 g2L L1^2 P2)/(
 L2^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^7) - (760 g20 g2L L1 P2)/(L2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^7) - (
 760 g20 g2L L2 P2)/(L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^7) - (416 g20 g2L L2^2 P2)/(
 L1^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^7) - (136 g20 g2L L2^3 P2)/(
 L1^3 (L1 + L2)^5 r^7) - (20 g20 g2L L2^4 P2)/(
 L1^4 (L1 + L2)^5 r^7) - (90 g20 g2L L1^2 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 6 g20 g2L L1^4 P)/(L2^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (36 g20 g2L L1^3 P)/(
 L2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (120 g20 g2L L1 L2 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 90 g20 g2L L2^2 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (36 g20 g2L L2^3 P)/(
 L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (6 g20 g2L L2^4 P)/(L1^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 268 g10 g1L L1^2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 290 g0 g2L L1^2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 62 g20 gL L1^2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (20 g0 g2L L1^6 P2)/(
 L2^4 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (8 g10 g1L L1^5 P2)/(
 L2^3 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (112 g0 g2L L1^5 P2)/(
 L2^3 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (52 g10 g1L L1^4 P2)/(
 L2^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (266 g0 g2L L1^4 P2)/(
 L2^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (2 g20 gL L1^4 P2)/(L2^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 152 g10 g1L L1^3 P2)/(L2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (352 g0 g2L L1^3 P2)/(
 L2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (16 g20 gL L1^3 P2)/(L2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 320 g10 g1L L1 L2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 160 g0 g2L L1 L2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 160 g20 gL L1 L2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 268 g10 g1L L2^2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 290 g0 g2L L2^2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 62 g20 gL L2^2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (152 g10 g1L L2^3 P2)/(
 L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (352 g0 g2L L2^3 P2)/(L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 16 g20 gL L2^3 P2)/(L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (52 g10 g1L L2^4 P2)/(
 L1^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (266 g0 g2L L2^4 P2)/(
 L1^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (2 g20 gL L2^4 P2)/(L1^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (
 8 g10 g1L L2^5 P2)/(L1^3 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (112 g0 g2L L2^5 P2)/(
 L1^3 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) - (20 g0 g2L L2^6 P2)/(
 L1^4 (L1 + L2)^5 r^5) + (5 g20 g2L L1^3)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^4) + (
 g20 g2L L1^4)/(L2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^4) + (
 10 g20 g2L L1^2 L2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^4) + (
 10 g20 g2L L1 L2^2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^4) + (
 5 g20 g2L L2^3)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^4) + (g20 g2L L2^4)/(
 L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^4) - (24 g10 g1L L1^4 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 70 g0 g2L L1^4 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 2 g20 gL L1^4 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (6 g0 g2L L1^6 P)/(
 L2^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (4 g10 g1L L1^5 P)/(L2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 32 g0 g2L L1^5 P)/(L2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 60 g10 g1L L1^3 L2 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 80 g0 g2L L1^3 L2 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 16 g20 gL L1^3 L2 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 80 g10 g1L L1^2 L2^2 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 72 g0 g2L L1^2 L2^2 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 28 g20 gL L1^2 L2^2 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 60 g10 g1L L1 L2^3 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 80 g0 g2L L1 L2^3 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 16 g20 gL L1 L2^3 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 24 g10 g1L L2^4 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 70 g0 g2L L2^4 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 2 g20 gL L2^4 P)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (4 g10 g1L L2^5 P)/(
 L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (32 g0 g2L L2^5 P)/(L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 6 g0 g2L L2^6 P)/(L1^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 32 g0 gL L1^4 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (2 g0 gL L1^6 P2)/(
 L2^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (12 g0 gL L1^5 P2)/(L2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 52 g0 gL L1^3 L2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 60 g0 gL L1^2 L2^2 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 52 g0 gL L1 L2^3 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (
 32 g0 gL L2^4 P2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (12 g0 gL L2^5 P2)/(
 L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^3) - (2 g0 gL L2^6 P2)/(L1^2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^3) + (
 g10 g1L L1^5)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 5 g0 g2L L1^5)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (g0 g2L L1^6)/(
 L2 (L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (5 g10 g1L L1^4 L2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 10 g0 g2L L1^4 L2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 g20 gL L1^4 L2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 10 g10 g1L L1^3 L2^2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 12 g0 g2L L1^3 L2^2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 3 g20 gL L1^3 L2^2)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 10 g10 g1L L1^2 L2^3)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 12 g0 g2L L1^2 L2^3)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 3 g20 gL L1^2 L2^3)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 5 g10 g1L L1 L2^4)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 10 g0 g2L L1 L2^4)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 g20 gL L1 L2^4)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 g10 g1L L2^5)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (
 5 g0 g2L L2^5)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (g0 g2L L2^6)/(L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^2)
```

where every term includes some powers of `L1` and `L2`, how can I retain only the ones where the powers of `L1` and `L2` at the numerator equal the ones at the denominator?

Example. Between the following three terms

```
(g10 g1L L2^5)/((L1 + L2)^5 r^2) + (5 g0 g2L L2^5)/((L1 + 
      L2)^6 r^2) + (g0 g2L L2^6)/(L1 (L1 + L2)^5 r^2)
```

I want to retain only the first and the third since, substituting (`L1=L` and `L2=L`) the second has five powers of `L` at the numerator but six at the denominator.

I tried using `Series`, expanding `L1` and `L2` around `Infinity` to first order but it is not useful. Can anyone find a "function" that does this work?

(Obviously I can use the substitution `L1=L` and `L2=L` to make the sum more readable but in this way I don't keep track of all the terms as functions of `L1` and `L2`, as I want).

Comment: You have a missing `(` on the first line of your code

Comment: Thanks! I corrected it.

Comment: Does `SeriesCoefficient[expr /. {L1 -> ϵ L1, L2 -> L2 ϵ}, {ϵ 0, 0}]` do what you want?

Comment: @CarlWoll yes! Thank you! Do you want to answer so I can vote yours as the right answer? Otherwise I can do it myself, thank you anyway.